# How to remove multiple strings in a Mysql column

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I would like to trim this string (these strings are stored in a single column)

```
 [17332] Rohayati Bakri [20611] Nazrie Haslieanie [20612] Nur Izzati
```

into this (also stored in a single column)

```
 Rohayati Bakri, Nazrie Haslieanie, Nur Izzati
```

**using only Mysql query**. The reference id -> [xxxxx] all have the same length.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support any kinds of regular expressions in `REPLACE`.  A brute force method is:

- Dump the table
- Replace strings with `sed`
- Import table

The commands are:

- `mysqldump -u login -p db your_table > dump.sql`
- `sed 's/\[[0-9]\{5\}\]//g' dump.sql > newdump.sql`
- `mysqlimport -u login -p db your_table < newdump.sql`

Potentially this could affect some other data that matches the pattern, so use this on your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

At a very generic level you can try it

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')
WHERE SomeOtherColumn LIKE '%PATTERN%'
```

In your case you say these were escaped but since you don't specify how they were escaped, let's say they were escaped to GREATERTHAN

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'GREATERTHAN', '<')
WHERE articleItemLIKE '%GREATERTHAN%'
```

Since your query is actually going to be working inside the string, your WHERE clause doing it's pattern matching is likely to improve any performance - it is actually going to generate more work for the server. Unless you have another WHERE clause member that is going to make this query perform better, you can simply do an update like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'GREATERTHAN', '<')
```

Coming in from a completely different angle:

You can do this when you select the data (not when you do save it)

So instead of :

```
SELECT MyURLString From MyTable
```

You can do

```
SELECT REPLACE (MyURLString, 'GREATERTHAN', '<') as MyURLString From MyTable
```

Comment: I should add that the given string in the question is stored inside a single column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try trim function also

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = SUBSTRING(col_name, 7)
```

It will trim first 7 caracters.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with regular expressions.

```
SELECT REPLACE(column, '\[[0-9]*\]', '') FROM table;
```

If MySQL supported them. Unfortunately MySQL does not support regular expressions in `REPLACE`.

But you could do it with a `UDF`. [Here](http://kovshenin.com/2011/regex-replace-in-mysql-or-lib_mysqludf_preg-in-ubuntu-linux/) is a post that might help you.